# Postgresql 9.2 on Centos 5, rails, bundle - PostgreSQL is too old

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, centos5

This is driving me nuts

First, my hosting provider that I have been with since the stone age, are dragging their feet about updating to Centos 6 and, from what I have read, I can see why.

Instead of waiting for the next ice age to pass, I read the [instructions for just updating postgresql 9.2 on Centos 5](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/install-postgresql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/), which is all I need to run my bundle install, which tells me that my PostgreSQL is too old - PostgreSQL 8.1.23

After updating and starting, here's the message back:

```
[root@vps data]# /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.2 start
/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions: fork: Cannot allocate memory
/etc/profile.d/lang.sh: line 53: /sbin/consoletype: Argument list too long
Starting postgresql-9.2 service:                           [  OK  ]
```

It started, great - right?

No,

```
[root@vps data]# psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 8.1.23
contains support for command-line editing
```

If 9.2 started, then why does it still say 8.1.23?

Maybe I just need to reboot

```
reboot -i
```

ssh back in psql --version still shows PostgreSQL 8.1.23 - WTF?

I run /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.2 start - it starts - OK, cool

```
bundle install

Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling

gem install pg -v '0.17.1'
```

I still receive the error:

```
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... no
Your PostgreSQL is too old. Either install an older version of this gem or upgrade your    database.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

So, my ultimate questions are:

If the postgresql 9.2 started, why does it say that I am running 8.1.23?

Do I have to rm -rf the entire /usr/bin/psql and start over?

Comment: This question sounds more like it's about setup of software rather than a programming-related question. I'm going to recommend that this question is moved to ServerFault where you'll get better (ie more experienced) devops-related help for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PostgreSQL Development Group has packages for Pg 9.3 on CentOS 5.

See [yum.postgresql.org](http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php).

However, installing Pg 9.3 won't remove 8.1. It'll still be on your `PATH`. It'll still be running, too.

If you want to use the 9.3 `psql` and `libpq`, you need to alter your `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to prefer the PostgreSQL 9.3 install. Then rebuild the `Pg` gem against the new `libpq`.

Something like:

```
export PATH="/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
gem uninstall pg
gem install pg
```

If you want this to take effect globally you can modify `/etc/ld.so.conf` to put the new path in place by default, and `/etc/environment` to set the `PATH` appropriately.

Otherwise, add the first two lines to your `~/.bash_profile`.

Separately, these are rather worrying:

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions: fork: Cannot allocate memory
/etc/profile.d/lang.sh: line 53: /sbin/consoletype: Argument list too long
```

as they suggest something is mismatched/broken on the system. Not necessarily PostgreSQL related. Have you force-installed any RPMs or used any 3rd party repos?

Comment: The /etc/postgresql-pgdg-libs.conf has the 9.2 path. I have only installed what is in the Gemfile and to my knowledge, no 3rd party repos. BTW, sorry for the late response, fell asleep - and still message of PostgreSQL to old, when trying to run gem install pg

Comment: In case you want to know how I fixed it:

rm -rf /usr/psql/bin
/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.2 start
gem install pg -- --with-opt-lib=/usr/postgresql-9.2/lib --with-pg-config=/usr/postgresql-9.2/bin/pg_config

# while searching for checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... no
gem install pg -v '< 0.13'
installed pg 0.12.1
vi Gemfile.lock
Changed 0.17.1 to 0.12.1
bundle install - successfull

Comment: BTW, thanks for your help guys - kronusproductions.com:3000 - total newbie at Rails, but it's a complete Angular/RoR project based on the github Cafe Townsend project

Comment: Also, I had to delete the /usr/bin/psql directory for the os to see the postgresql-9.2, along with initializing the 9.2. I think it is kind of strange though, because I am using sqlite3 for the db

Comment: Argh, don't delete directly from `/usr`. Uninstall the package with rpm / dpkg instead.

Comment: I was going nuts with this and nothing helped untill I realized that postgresql-devel and postgresql-libs were from 8.1.23!
So yum install postgresql94-libs and postgresql94-devel did the trick!