# Rails: How to use most recent version of Postgres in Rails (Your version of PostgreSQL (80422) is too old. Active Record supports PostgreSQL >= 9.1.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am getting the following error when I run rails db:migrate

```
rails aborted!
Your version of PostgreSQL (80422) is too old. Active Record supports PostgreSQL >= 9.1.
/home/alex/lighthouse/whiteshark-backend/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/alex/lighthouse/whiteshark-backend/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/alex/lighthouse/whiteshark-backend/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have PostgreSQL 9.6.2 installed but Rails doesn't seem to recognise it.
I also tried this solution to no avail:
[Postgresql 9.2 on Centos 5, rails, bundle - PostgreSQL is too old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626366/postgresql-9-2-on-centos-5-rails-bundle-postgresql-is-too-old)

Please help!

Comment: http://blog.techium.jp/entry/2016/11/18/232910 translate this with google translator in chrome I feel you can find an answer there

Comment: Hey Kick Buttowski, I'm getting this error:  $ sudo yum -y localinstall https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/testing/10/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat10-10-1.noarch.rpm 
...
Error: Package: pgdg-redhat10-10-1.noarch (/pgdg-redhat10-10-1.noarch)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: pgdg-redhat10-10-1.noarch (/pgdg-redhat10-10-1.noarch)
           Requires: redhat-release
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest ... Any ideas?